# Django - Filter based on model method

Tags: django

I have a model, defined like this :

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, default='', blank=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField('date created', default=timezone.now())

    def was_published_today(self):
        today = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        return self.creation_date >= today
```

I would like to filter a set of Item like this :

```
items = Item.objects.filter(was_published_today=True)
```

But I run into a `FieldError` which makes sense as it seems that filter is not made to filter a set of objects based on a method. Detailed error :

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'was_published_today' into field. Choices are : creation_date, name
```

What is the correct way to do this ? I know I can compare `creation_date` with today's date but that's what `was_published_today` does and I would like to keep it DRY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can use django [Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/).

Custom Manager:

```
class GetPublishedToday(models.Manager):
      def get_query_set(self):
        return super(GetPublishedToday, self).get_query_set().filter(creation_date= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1))
```

in Models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, default='', blank=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField('date created', default=timezone.now())
    was_published_today= GetPublishedToday()
```

in views:

```
items = Item.was_published_today.all()  # or .filter(name= "foobar")
```

'''PS: Its an untested code.'''

Comment: Thanks ! That did the trick excepted in the Manager part where I used `creation_date__gte` instead of `creation_date`.

Answer (score 0):

[F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters) is a correct way, I think. Example from documentation:

```
from datetime import timedelta
Entry.objects.filter(mod_date__gt=F('pub_date') + timedelta(days=3))
```

Comment: I don't think so. As stated in the documentation, `F expressions` refer to the value of a model field, not to one of its method ([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/queries/#django.db.models.F)).

Comment: You cannot use one of model's method in filter anyway, because of queryset must build a sql query.

Comment: @erthalion Sounds so simple when you say it that way, but I wracked my brains trying to come up with the "correct" way to do this, when the simplest way was correct all along. :)